# How do I open an app in my new mac book pro

Tags: macbook-pro

I just bought a new mac book pro.  I am pretty sure I transferred my apps from my iPad to my mac book pro.  How do I open the apps now in my new mac book pro?  I can see all my apps in the iTunes library but when I double click on them, nothing happens.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Please understand that iOS Apps are not supported by or built for OS X, therefore they will not run on your new MacBook Pro unfortunately.

If you take a look on the App Store, you should be able to find the OS X equivalents for the apps you'd like to use on your MBP - though you'd most likely have to purchase them again if they aren't free.

Answer (score 2):

Those apps are for iOS meaning iPad and iPhone only. They are designed for touch. To get apps that have an equivalent for OS X, go to the Mac App Store. The reason you see them in iTunes is because these are backups for your iPad.

1. Click the  on your menu bar. (Top left)
2. Click **App Store**
3. Search for the apps you want

If not available on Mac, you can contact the developer to see if they have plans to make a corresponding Mac app.